# Which is faster : get array from $_SESSION or from json file?

Tags: php, json, file-io, session-variables

here is my dilemma :

I am creating a multilingual platform. In that purpose I created json files containing all the translated text for each language.

Now when the user land on a their page I read from that file and store the array of translations in the $_SESSION variable such as

```
$_SESSION['website_text'] = json_decode(file_get_contents("content_".$language.".json"), true);
```

Then everytime I want to echo text on the views I access the element from the session array :

```
$text = $_SESSION['website_text']['paragraph2_headline'];
```

Now I am wondering, since the $_SESSION is stored on the server. Is it faster to read from the session like I do or to read everytime from the file and decode the json? 
The second option would go like that :

```
$website_text = json_decode(file_get_contents("content_".$language.".json"), true);
$text =  $website['paragraph2_headline'];
```

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Did you test anything? You can keep track of time that youre script runs.

Comment: @Jashwant how would opening a local file would create an http request?

Comment: asside from $_SESSION and file, you could also cache it using APC or memcache, which is definetly faster since the storage is the RAM

Comment: @VladBalmos, I was wrong, deleted my answer.

Comment: I have not tested it indeed, but since I took it as a common dilemma for developers, I preferred asking first.

Comment: @VladBalmos we haven't set up APC or memcache on our production server yet, but it would be worth looking into it.

Comment: To sum up: reading from the Session in probably faster but involve duplication. Instead of reading from a json file I could generate a php array file and read from it directly which is both fast and avoid duplication. APC or memcache might be even more efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely it's faster when pulling the data from `$_SESSION`, but `$_SESSION` is not a good place to store localization data in because it will end up being duplicated for each user.

When you retrieve the strings from `$_SESSION` then PHP has to read the data from the session file (which it already does to read any other session data, so the cost of opening the file is somewhat amortized) and run `unserialize` on it; if you retrieve it from a JSON file then it has open the file, read it and run `json_decode`. `unserialize` should be faster than `json_decode`, but please don't quote me on that.

If you are interested in making this fast, it would be better to read the strings directly from a PHP file where they are stored as an array:

```
// content_en.php
<?php
return array(
    'welcome' => 'Welcome to our website!',
    // ...
);
```

Even if your localization files are in JSON it would be very easy to "compile" the JSON into PHP and use the PHP code as a cache:

```
$lang = 'en';

$sourceFile = 'content_'.$lang.'.json';
$cacheFile = 'content_'.$lang.'.cache.php';
if (!is_file($cacheFile)) {
    $content = json_decode(file_get_contents($sourceFile), true);
    file_put_contents($cacheFile, "<?php\n return ".var_export($content, true).";");
}
else {
    $content = include($cacheFile);
}
```

Comment: we think the same, as create a fast access cache in native PHP code, but you code is beter

Comment: Those are two very good points. Indeed, I duplicated the data in every session but if indeed it is faster it might be worth it because the this is an operation I do for every piece of text and overall it would make a noticeable difference to the user.

Comment: @Tristan: I hope you only load the content (in whatever manner you choose) once for every script, not for every string translation -- I was somewhat confused by your comment. But anyway, loading straight PHP code is the fastest.

Comment: @FIG-GHD742: Tip: `var_export` lets you get rid of the `serialize`/`unserialize` overhead.

Comment: @Jon Yes sorry it was confusing. In the first solution, I load it only once and then I read from the session but in the second case, I would read from the file everytime.

Comment: @Tristan: Definitely **do not** read from the file everytime. Keep the contents around in a variable so you can refer to them again next time.

Comment: @Jon Yep now it's pretty clear to me, I guess session_start() that I call before generating a view through AJAX is the equivalent of reading from the file and then the array would have to be stored anyways as a global variable in the same way $_SESSION does.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about JSON, but I know for the `$_SESSION` is save as 
a file on the server with

```
file_put_contents($path, serialize($_SESSION));
```

And read as

```
$_SESSION = unserialize(file_get_contents($path));
```

Yes as Jon say, if you will has speed, format this as native PHP code or we can save the data as a PHP file in this exemple.

```
function save_data($path,$data) {
     file_put_contents($path, "<?php $data=unserialize('".addslashes(serialize($data))."'); ?>");
}
```

And for load this is only to include the file and then get the data from $data.

Answer (score 0):

In both examples you gave us, you store your localization data in file but process them in different way, one in variable other in session.

Question should be "How to process a localization data efficient"

Comment: This is a good point, I'm quite novice to localization data and I am going step by step here but obviously it would be worth looking in a wider perspective.